# How can I change background image in JFrame using JButtons?

Tags: jframe, jbutton

I want to change the image background of a JFrame using a button. I know how to use JFrame and Jbutton.

Answer (score 0):

you should add the following code in your button action listener

```
setContentPane(new JLabel(new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Computer\\Downloads\\colorful design.png")));
```